# How to get data on datatable by calling stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored-procedure like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectUserInfo] 

AS
BEGIN
select * from User_Info
END
```

and I am using `LINQ` to call this procedure and want store the data in a `datatable` or `dataset`
here what I am doing :

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
DataTable dt = null;
dt = (DataTable)dc.SelectUserInfo();
```

but its not working its giving error.

the error is this :

> Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult`1[SelectUserInfoResult]' to type
>   'System.Data.DataTable'.

Please help me to do this ...

Comment: i have included the error now please take a look

Comment: I don't think you can directly cast the results to the DataTable. The results is of type `SelectUserInfoResults` which you must have defined it in some function import.

Comment: can you explain or show how ...

Comment: One of the points of LINQ is to avoid using datasets. The idea is that instead you have a collection of entities.

Comment: the thing is i have a method inside a class which i want to return datatable or dataset so i can call that method in my application and have a datatable

Comment: @ArindamDas You have to convert your `ISingleResult<T>` into a `DataTable`, all the `Properties` of each item of type `T` will become the corresponding `DataColumn` and each item will correspond to a `DataRow`. There is some code out there which has already done that for you, just do some search with correct keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you really do need a DataTable/DataSet.

The DBML file **creates a return class for your Stored Procedure**, in your case there is a class `SelectUserInfoResults` that got created when you added the stored procedure SelectUserInfo to your dbml file.

So if you are not being forced to use DataTables/DataSet you could simply create a `List<SelectUserInfoResults>` as your return type.

DataTables/DataSets and Linq To Entities classes are of very different nature, I would recommend to avoid mixing them whenever possible.